# Convert from integer to dictionary with repeating digits

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I need to take an integer `n` and add all its digits into a Python dictionary *(hashtable)* to later access them with an `O(1)` complexity.

```
n = 941726149

d = {}
for i in str(n):
    d[i] = None
print(d)
```

The problem is when there are repeating digits, the dictionary overrides them changing its order. For example, the above code outputs:

```
{'9': None, '4': None, '1': None, '7': None, '2': None, '6': None}
```

But the output I need is :

```
{'9': None, '4': None, '1': None, '7': None, '2': None, '6': None, '1': None, '4': None, '9': None}
```

I know it's **impossible** to add repeating keys into a *hashtable*, so I'm wondering if that data structure can be modified to fit this behavior, or use another `(maybe custom)` structure that supports it.

### Edit

Example input and **output**:

- n = 123455   **d[5] = [4, 5]**
- n = 987385   **d[8] = [1, 4] | d[9] = [0]**

Comment: You can not repeat key in `dictionary` or `hash_table`

Comment: Sounds like an *XY Problem*. What's the end goal?

Comment: This currently sounds like an XY problem. Maybe if you tell us what you want to do with the "dict", we can give some advise. With all your values being ``None``, there's no difference using only a set over a dict, but still there won't be repeating items.

Comment: if you repeat key in `dict` you can not access them later in `O(1)` then this take `O(n)`

Comment: @cristifati Accessing the digits on the input number `n` with an `O(1)` complexity

Comment: `str(n)[index]`?

Comment: @cristifati I thought about allowing repeating digits and inserting every occurrence of each digit in a linked list, but it no longer meets `O(1)` complexity. Also, I have to be sure about the construction complexity of the `str(n)` value.

Comment: give us multiple sample input and desired output

Comment: Maybe a dict of dicts? Assuming you also want to keep track of the position of the digit it could be something like `{9 : {0 : None, 8: None}, ..., 7 : {3 : None}, ...}, meaning the 9 exists in position 0 and 8, the 7 in position 3 only, and so on. This will _almost_ be O(1)

Comment: How do you want to use the structure afterwards? Please provide some details. What should something like `d[9]` return? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @cristifati You're right, I'm going to add some examples to the question.

Comment: @gimix I think the dict of dicts can work, please let me try it out.

Comment: How about using `defaultdict` to store similar digit in a list then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example, that for each digit present in the number, it stores its indexes. 
As a note, digits not present in the number won't be present in the structure either, so trying to index them (`structure[digit_not_existing_in_number]`) will yield *KeyError* (that's why *dict.get* is required). But that can be easily fixed.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


def o1_access_structure(n):
    ret = {}
    for i, e in enumerate(str(n)):
        ret.setdefault(int(e), []).append(i)
    return ret


def main(*argv):
    ns = (
        123455,
        987385,
        941726149,
    )

    for n in ns:
        print("\n", n)
        s = o1_access_structure(n)
        for e in range(10):
            print("  ", e, s.get(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q072713761]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
>  123455
>    0 None
>    1 [0]
>    2 [1]
>    3 [2]
>    4 [3]
>    5 [4, 5]
>    6 None
>    7 None
>    8 None
>    9 None
>
>  987385
>    0 None
>    1 None
>    2 None
>    3 [3]
>    4 None
>    5 [5]
>    6 None
>    7 [2]
>    8 [1, 4]
>    9 [0]
>
>  941726149
>    0 None
>    1 [2, 6]
>    2 [4]
>    3 None
>    4 [1, 7]
>    5 None
>    6 [5]
>    7 [3]
>    8 None
>    9 [0, 8]
>
> Done.
> ```

**Or, if you don't care about the digit indexes**, but only their presence / frequency, you could use [[Python.Docs]: class collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> ```py
> >>> from collections import Counter
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> c = Counter(int(e) for e in str(941726149))
> >>>
> >>> for e in range(10):
> ...     print(e, c[e])
> ...
> 0 0
> 1 2
> 2 1
> 3 0
> 4 2
> 5 0
> 6 1
> 7 1
> 8 0
> 9 2
> ```